# Best way to write application data to a file in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the **Caliburn.Micro MVVM pattern**.

I am writing an application that has 2 DataGrids, one holds a `BindableCollection` of `RepairOrder`, the other a `BindableCollection` `WriteOff`.

`BindableCollection_WriteOff` is property of `BindableCollection_RepairOrder`. (See the below code).

I need to find a way to write all the `RepairOrder` including the `WriteOff` associated with each RO.  Besides `RepairOrder` class holding the `WriteOff` class, the `WriteOff` class does not have a way to tie the `WriteOff` to a `RepairOrder`.

**Repair Order Class:**

```
public class RepairOrder
{
    public string Schedule { get; set; }
    public string ControlNumber { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public double OrgValue { get; set; }

    private List<WriteOff> _myWriteOffs;

    public List<WriteOff> GetMyWriteOffs()
    {

        return _myWriteOffs;
    }

    public void AddMyWriteOff(WriteOff value)
    { _myWriteOffs.Add(value); }

    public void DeleteMyWriteOff(WriteOff value)
    { _myWriteOffs.Remove(value); }


    public RepairOrder(string CN, string SC, double VL)
    {
        ControlNumber = CN;
        Schedule = SC;
        Value = Math.Round(VL, 2);
        Note = null;
        _myWriteOffs = new List<WriteOff>();
    }

    public RepairOrder()
    {
        _myWriteOffs = new List<WriteOff>();
    }

    public static RepairOrder FromCSV(string CSVLine, string Sched)
    {
        string[] values = CSVLine.Split(',');
        RepairOrder rep = new RepairOrder();
        rep.ControlNumber = values[2];
        rep.Value = Math.Round(double.Parse(values[5]),2);
        rep.Age = int.Parse(values[4]);
        rep.Schedule = Sched;
        return rep;
    }         
}
```

**Write Off Class:**

```
public class WriteOff
{
    private string _store;
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double WriteOffAmount { get; set; }
    public string Schedule { get; set; }
    public string Store
    {
        get {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_store)) return "";
            string temp = _store.Substring(0, 3);
            return temp;
        }
        set { _store = value; }
    }
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public WriteOff(string Acct, string Desc, double Amount, string _store)
    {
        Account = Acct;
        Description = Desc;
        WriteOffAmount = Amount;
        Store = _store;
    }

    public string GetWOAccount() {
        string SchedAccountNumber = "";
        //{ "Navistar", "Cummins", "Misc", "Kenworth", "Mack/Volvo" }


        switch (Account)
        {
            case "Navistar":
                SchedAccountNumber = "222000";
                break;
            case "Cummins":
                SchedAccountNumber = "223000";
                break;
            case "Misc":
                SchedAccountNumber = "224500";
                break;
            default:
                SchedAccountNumber = "";
                break;
        }

        return SchedAccountNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you should have a Database - even a simple in process one - rather then a plain file as backend Storage.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/